# MATLAB Nan problem ( validation loss and mini batch loss) in Transfer Learning with SSD ResNet50

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, object-detection, nan, transfer-learning

I am trying to use SSD Resnet50 for transfer Learning on a data set (Images) with a resolution of 640x360, with one class as output. I followed the example of Matlab for vehicle detection.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/object-detection-using-single-shot-detector.html
I set the network input size to [300 300] and kept the same options for training.
However, when training starts, in the first iteration both the mini-batch loss and the validation loss go to NAN.
Following suggestions and answers on this forum, I start by lowering the learning rate and I tested several values 1e-1, 1e-3, 1e-5, 1e-15, I changed also the VerboseFrequency to 50, 10 and 1 but I get the same errors (mini batch loss and the validation loss go to NAN).
I tried also to initialize the weights and the bias of the first conv layer with lower values, however, I get the same error.

```
conv01 = convolution2dLayer([7,7],64,'Stride',2,'Padding',[3,3,3,3],'BiasLearnRateFactor',1,'name','conv1');
conv01.Weights = gpuArray(single(randn([7 7 3 64])*1e-15));
conv01.Bias = gpuArray(single(randn([1 1 64])*0.00001+1));
```

I tried to run the vehicle detection example and it runs perfectly, so I double-checked my data, the images in my dataset is in jpg format in 8bits as in vehicle dataset.
I think I am missing something here. I have attached the script plus a screenshot of the output that shows the Nan below.
Any help is very appreciated.

```
addpath('C:\dataset');
%%
%Load the pedestrian ground truth data.
data = load('labelling640360.mat');
gTruth = data.gTruth;
pedestriandataset=[gTruth.DataSource.Source data.gTruth.LabelData];
pedestriandataset.Properties.VariableNames([1])={'imageFilename'};
pedestriandataset(1:4,:)
summary(pedestriandataset)
 
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Split the data 
%Use 60% of the data for training set and the rest for the test set.
rng(0);
shuffledIndices = randperm(height(pedestriandataset));
idx = floor(0.6 * length(shuffledIndices));
trainingDataTbl = pedestriandataset(shuffledIndices(1:idx), :);
testDataTbl = pedestriandataset(shuffledIndices(idx+1:end), :);
 
%Create an image datastore for loading the images.
imdsTrain = imageDatastore(trainingDataTbl.imageFilename);
imdsTest = imageDatastore(testDataTbl.imageFilename);
 
% Create a datastore for the ground truth bounding boxes.
bldsTrain = boxLabelDatastore(trainingDataTbl(:, 2:end));
bldsTest = boxLabelDatastore(testDataTbl(:, 2:end));
 
% Combine the image and box label datastores.
trainingData = combine(imdsTrain, bldsTrain);
testData = combine(imdsTest, bldsTest);
 
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   SSD   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
inputSize = [300 300 3];
%Define number of object classes to detect.
numClasses = width(pedestriandataset)-1;
%Create the SSD object detection network.
lgraph = ssdLayers(inputSize, numClasses, 'resnet50'); %'vgg16'
analyzeNetwork(lgraph);
% plot(lgraph)
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
augmentedTrainingData = transform(trainingData,@augmentData);
augmentedData = cell(4,1);
for k = 1:4
    data = read(augmentedTrainingData);
    augmentedData{k} = insertShape(data{1},'Rectangle',data{2});
    reset(augmentedTrainingData);
end
 
figure
montage(augmentedData,'BorderSize',10)
 
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preprocess the augmented training data to prepare for training
preprocessedTrainingData = transform(augmentedTrainingData,@(data)preprocessData(data,inputSize));
% Read the preprocessed training data.
data = read(preprocessedTrainingData);
%Display the image and bounding boxes.
I = data{1};
bbox = data{2};
annotatedImage = insertShape(I,'Rectangle',bbox);
annotatedImage = imresize(annotatedImage,2);
figure
imshow(annotatedImage)
 
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Train SSD Object Detector %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', 'MiniBatchSize', 16, ....
        'InitialLearnRate',1e-1, 'LearnRateSchedule', 'piecewise', ...
        'LearnRateDropPeriod', 30, 'LearnRateDropFactor', 0.8, ...
        'MaxEpochs', 300, 'VerboseFrequency', 50, ...        
        'CheckpointPath', tempdir, 'Shuffle','every-epoch'); %'ExecutionEnvironment','cpu'
 
[detector, info] = trainSSDObjectDetector(preprocessedTrainingData,lgraph,options);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try use adam as a solver in the training options.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30245584)

Comment: Hi Amer, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, using adam as a solver  does not resolve the issue